# Migrating DNS Settings from Office 365 to Google Apps

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, microsoft-office-365

I need to migrate my company from using Office 365 to using Google Apps. I have backed up our email to .pst files. The big remaining task is migrating the DNS settings. Our company uses GoDaddy. I'm not sure which records I need to update in the Zone file.

- The CName records seem to point to a lot of Office 365 stuff. I don't know if I need to change these records or delete them or what.
- I'm not sure what to change the MX record to.
- Do I need a TXT record? Right now it shows @ v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
- What about the NS records?

Thank you so much for your help. I am primarily on the software development side and our Network admin just quit. I am familiar enough with this stuff to just be dangerous. I sincerely appreciate any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 1):

A transition from Office 365 to Google Apps is a pretty big deal.  In order to move over the DNS settings, you need to delete any Office 365 related DNS records.

A CNAME is simply a pointer to another web address in Office 365's case.  You most likely have one that is mail, or email or something like that.  This points you to the website in which you access your mail.  You can point that record towards the new site (which Google should provide you).

The MX records should be provided by Google when you setup the domain in Google.  You need to remove all the old Office 365 records in order to start routing email to Gmail.  This in most cases means removing all of the MX records.  If you have an on-premise exchange server, or route through a separate anti-spam service such as postini you will need to change the MX records inside the control panel of that service.

The TXT records are in your case most likely domain verification, domain keys, and SPF records.  Google will also provide you replacement records for these.

The NS records should definitely not be touched.  These probably point to GoDaddy's DNS servers, which is where your CNAME and MX records are probably held.

Good luck, next time give more details, as I am making a lot of assumptions.